# Is there a way to read a RecordBatch from bytes, and pass in the schema directly?

Tags: javascript, apache-arrow

The methods we've found in the "apache-arrow" JS package to create a RecordBatchReader either require you to pass an `ArrowJSONLike` which I believe requires your batches to be in JSON, or require you to pass it an ([encapsulated](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/format/Columnar.html#encapsulated-message-format)?) message in the form of a stream of bytes which requires you to have the schema as part of that message, alongside the bytes for the actual batch.

Is it possible for us to create a Reader where we pass the bytes of a RecordBatch but also manually pass an already deserialized Schema?

Comment: Is your goal to save CPU cycles (e.g. don't waste time parsing the schema) or is it to do some kind of cast (e.g. my schema interprets this column differently than the stored schema) or is it error checking (e.g. my schema said this column should be string, raise an error) or is it something else entirely?

Comment: @Pace we actually don't store the schema alongside the batch. We can have many batches that that are written in shared memory that all share the same schema.

And per your first question, we do want to save CPU cycles, and we don't want to have to duplicate code or data, or spend time deserializing the batch into JSON or vice versa if we already have them accessible.